# Is there a plugin for Visual Studio to clean up CSS?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I'm looking for a plugin for Visual Studio 2010 to help me clean up my CSS in a ASP.NET MVC project.

We are a lot of people working on the same website and before I publish it, I wanna clean up the CSS to make sure there are no unused selectors.

I know that there are plugin for Firefox, but they won't catch any dynamically loaded CSS and usually they just check one page.

Comment: unused definitions? did u mean unused selectors?

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry about that, changed my question

Comment: But how would that handle dynamic content? and I would need to publish the site before I publish it. And another thing I don't like about that kind of solution usually you build your site with templates ex. if your have a site with product with over 100.000 products, then an online scanner would need to scan all product site. If it was done in Visual studio if would only need to scan the source code for the product template.

Comment: https://purifycss.online/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this plugin for Visual Studio

**CSSCop** from Mads Kristensen

Its not perfect, but its a great start and its free

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a921b98e-9430-4be2-bf53-1169e12bdb50

From 2015 onward you need to use https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vsgallery/6edc26d4-47d8-4987-82ee-7c820d79be1d